# Multi-select all highlighted lines?

Tags: phpstorm

In Sublime, I commonly use my cursor to select multiple lines, then use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to select each line with multiple cursors.

I'm unable to find any documentation or pre-built option within `PHPStorm` that can handle this.

Does anyone have a solution? Thanks!.

Comment: Deleted my prev comment as I have misunderstood the request at first. Anyway -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-122181 -- check stuff there. One of the comments mentions [Extra Actions plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8213-extra-actions) .. but I'm not sure if it's compatible with PhpStorm...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR:** `⌥` + Shift + Drag does what you want. On keymap you can also select the Sublime key binding template for general familiarity.

**Overview**

A great overview of multiple cursors in Jetbrains products and 4 minutes well spent (some minor variants may be present in the exact bindings, but not hard to work out) is:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBkGOPR3-nA

**Three answers to your question:**

**1. Out of the box**

`⌥` + Shift + Drag does what you want.

Also relevant:

Press `⌥` (Option) twice, and then without releasing it, press up or down arrow keys. That will add a caret at the start of each line.

There are many more variations:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Multicursor.html
https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/03/working-with-multiple-selection-in-phpstorm-8-eap/

**2. Keymap templates**

If you go to `preferences -> keymap` you will find a dropdown with a list of templates. You can select Sublime Text or Sublime Text (OS).  This is not always perfect because other plugins can override the key bindings in sometimes opaque ways, so not every single binding ports; but it should bring you a whole bunch of familiarity.

**3. Custom**

You can create your own key and mouse bindings for any PHPStorm action by going to `preferences -> keymap` and right clicking on the action; or searching for an action and then right clicking, etc.